# python: get robot test case name

Tags: python, robotframework

I want to create in Python a function, that gets a test case name (robotframework) where some var was found, something like the line before with column=0 (text_line_column_0) after a specific value (var1) is detected. The purpose of this function, its to detect when a change is made on a test case (Git), this function will only be executed if var1 is in test cases area.

```
*** Test Cases ***
robot_test_case_1
    line values line values line values
    var1
    line values line values line values
    
    
robot_test_case_2
    line values line values line values
    line values line values line values
    var1
    line values line values line values
```

This is a example, I want to find in a robot file a specific line (obtained with git) and the test case related to that line.
My idea is if a test case (`*** test cases ***`) has been modified, I want to execute that test automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that could be further improved based on exact requirements. The steps:

1. Create a `--name-only` git diff and filter out the files that do not contain test cases. This is done by the `get_changed_robot_files` function.
2. Next step is to retrieve all test cases names from the collected files. This is done by the `get_list_of_all_tests_in_files` function which parses the .robot files recursively using the `collect_tests_from_suite` function. This utilizes [Robot Framework API](https://robot-framework.readthedocs.io/en/v3.2.2/index.html) so you do not have to reinvent the wheel here.
3. Get a full git diff and check which test cases are present in it. This is done with `get_changed_tests`. Now this is not 100% accurate some test cases will show up that has not been changed but the ones that have been change will be included. You can improve the diff analysis if needed. This gave the best results with the least effort right now.
4. Last step is to launch the affected tests utilizing the `robot.run.run_cli(arguments=None, exit=True)` [Robot Framework API call](https://robot-framework.readthedocs.io/en/v3.2.2/autodoc/robot.html#robot.run.run_cli) in `run_changed_tests`.

```python
import subprocess
import os
from robot.api import TestData
from robot import run_cli

def collect_tests_from_suite(suite, tests):
    for test in suite.testcase_table:
        tests.append(test.name)
    for child in suite.children:
        collect_tests_from_suite(child, tests)
        
def get_changed_robot_files():
    result = subprocess.run(["git", "diff", "--name-only", "HEAD~1", "HEAD"], capture_output=True, text=True)
    files = result.stdout
    return [f for f in files.split('\n') if ('.robot' in f) and ('__init__' not in f)]

def get_git_diff():
    result = subprocess.run(["git", "diff", "HEAD~1", "HEAD", '--unified=0'], capture_output=True, text=True)
    return result.stdout
    
def get_list_of_all_tests_in_files(files):
    tests = []
    for f in files:
        suite = TestData(source=f)
        collect_tests_from_suite(suite, tests)
    
    return tests
    
def get_changed_tests(tests):
    list_of_changed_tests = []
    diff = get_git_diff()
    
    for test in tests:
        if test in diff:        
            list_of_changed_tests.append(test)
            
    return list_of_changed_tests
    
def run_changed_tests(tests):
    args = []

    for test in tests:
        args.append('--test')
        args.append(test)

    args.append('.')
    
    rc = run_cli(args, exit=False)
    
# -------------------------------------------------- #
files = get_changed_robot_files()
tests = get_list_of_all_tests_in_files(files)
changed_tests = get_changed_tests(tests)

print(f'Files changed: {len(files)}')
print(f'Tests found:   {len(tests)}')
print(f'Tests changed: {len(changed_tests)}')

run_changed_tests(changed_tests)
```

Improvement ideas:

- Detect changed `__init__.robot` files and execute every suite below them.
- Detect changed `.resource` files and execute every `.robot` file that imports them.
- Improve diff parsing to exclude unchanged test cases.

Comment: Thnks a lot, I 'll try this code later. I didn't have time to try anything, because of the covid lockdown in Portugal / teleworking / childs

Comment: @TiagoFeitor Understandable :) It took me for a while as well to get some time and post an answer.

Comment: Hi, i got the following error, when I try to use the robot.api package.
 from robot.api import TestData
ImportError: No module named api

Comment: @TiagoFeitor What framework version do you use?

Comment: But I got the same error, for example with logger. I'm trying to understand how I can use these packages without a robot call